# First time in Paris - decent questions regarding transportation and tourist attractions

Tags: public-transport, tips-and-tricks, paris, fees-and-charges, the-louvre

**About my journey:**

I will be travelling to Paris in the beginning of March with my girlfriend and staying for 3 days.

We are landing at *Paris Beauvais Tille Airport*. I have unfortunately found that the airport is kinda far away from the city, but understood from their website that there are a lot of methods to get between the airport and *Porte Maillot*.

We will be staying at a hotel near *Parc Suzanne Lenglen* (Bd. Gambetta).

---

**Questions:**

1. **Travelling** : Hope that I am not wrong, but I was considering travelling through town by Metro (from downtown to the hotel, from a tourist attraction to another, etc). I searched for ticket prices on their website and found that 10 tickets are €12.70. Are the tickets available on any Metro line? (I will need to switch metros every now and then). Do you suggest buying a 3 day pass? Or better individual tickets?
2. **Must see tourist attractions** : I've seen where *La tour Eiffel*, *La Louvre* or *La cathédrale Notre-Dame* are situated. I would like to know what other must-see places you suggest (preferably somewhere downtown, but this is not a must as long as there is a metro station nearby). Any suggestion is welcomed - from museums to nice parks or picturesque buildings, monuments, etc.
3. **Travelling between tourist attractions** : Do you recommend walking every now and then between the tourist attractions? For example I saw there are 3.5 km between *La Tour Eiffel* and *La Louvre*. Is it worthwhile walking this distance? Meaning that if it is a nice area to travel by foot.
4. **Admission fees for the attractions** : I saw for example on the *Louvre*'s website that `Admission to the Louvre and the Musée Eugène Delacroix is free for the following visitor categories: 18-25 year-old residents of the European Economic Area (EU, Iceland, Norway, and Liechtenstein)`. Can anyone confirm? Are there any other discounts for students? Do they apply if I am a student in my own country and provide proper documents? I hope we will not be spending too much on entrance fees where we go.

Any other comments, proposals and any kind of feedback is more than welcomed. If anything else pops up in my mind I will put it here.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What kinds of things are you planning to see? Famous buildings? Museums? Art Galleries? Modern Art? Classical Art? Contemporary Art? Churches? Parks? Cemeteries? That'll affect quite a bit

Comment: For museum costs and transport, I'd suggest you read [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13233/are-there-days-times-dates-when-most-paris-museums-are-free) and [this one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13231/is-there-a-paris-equivalent-of-londons-oyster-pay-as-you-go) which cover some of what you want to know!

Comment: Those are really different questions. I'd suggest splitting this question up and asking each question separately.

Comment: see also http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/8590/46

Comment: Voted to close it. You should split your questions into several questions.

Comment: Also voted to close it. It is overly broad and most sub questions will be answered by most touguides or wikitravel or wikivoyage

Comment: If your wikitavel/wikivyage argument was taken seriously, many more questions would have to be closed ....

Comment: But I totally agree that the question is too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a lot you asked and even more to answer so as gerrit suggested, you can separate questions.

**1 and 3: Travelling**
To come from Beauvais to Paris, you will have to take the [16 € bus](http://www.aeroportbeauvais.com/bus.php?lang=eng) which will let you in Porte Maillot.
Paris is very little, you can easily walk between attractions (except Montmartre).
You can use a ticket t+ for any metro, tramway, bus. And also for the suburban train called RER but only inside Paris (zone 1).
The 3 day pass costs 23.40 €, not worth it in my opinion, you are not gonna use 20 tickets alone in 3 days unless you eat some.

Visit [ratp.fr](http://ratp.fr/) for more info on public transports.
You can also use the very cheap bicycle system, the [vélib](http://velib.fr) (1.70 €/day, if each trip < 30 min).

**2 and 4: Attractions**
The only main attraction outside of Paris is Versailles and its castle which is in zone 4.
Yes, most museums and other touristic places are free (or with a discount) for EU residents under 26. Check official website for more details. (Beware of closing days.)
Montmartre is in the north of Paris, the is a a nice view of Paris, a church called Sacré-Cœur, Moulin Rouge, it's also [Amélie](http://imdb.com/title/tt0211915/)'s district (the bar, the grocery shop).
Also, cimetière du Père-Lachaise (Jim Morrisson, Oscar Wilde) and Parc des Buttes-Chaumont.

Answer (score 4):

Targeting Question 1:

You mentioned you're under 26 and you're travelling in the beginning of march. If you're in Paris on a weekend check out the "[Ticket Jeunes Week-end](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/c_21580/ticket-jeunes-week-end/)". Unfortunately there is no english version of this site. It costs **3,65€ per day for zone 1-3**. It was perfect on my last visit. To buy the ticket just head for the ticket office and ask for "Jeunes Weekend" and try to pronounce it as french as you can :D

-Jeunes means youth so it for people under 26

-only valid on saturdays, sundays and puplic holiday

-you have to put your name on the ticket

[image]

Comment: btw I love travelling Paris being under 26

Comment: Wow, this is great information! I studied French for like 6 years, hopefully I can get it right. I understood what it is about. Thank you again very much for this info.

Comment: You'll be fine!